# Must I put source code .cs files to App_Code folder in VS 2012 Express?

Tags: visual-studio-2012

In my mind, all source code .cs files must be put to  App_Code folder.
but in the sample "Wingtip Toys"
http://www.asp.net/web-forms/tutorials/aspnet-45/getting-started-with-aspnet-45-web-forms/introduction-and-overview
I find some source code .cs files  is put the folder Logic, why?

Answer (score 0):

(I know this was asked 9 months ago but here's my answer for posterity.)

The App_Code folder was used for "Web Site" type projects introduced with ASP .NET 2.0. From what I gather, there was a bit of a back-and-forth in Visual Studio about how web apps should be built -- web site vs. web app.

In a "Web Site" project, all code stays in its folders and IIS compiles dynamically. whatever you put into the App_Code folder would be made into a strong type.

"Web App" projects do not use the App_Code folder since all code is compiled before deployment. You can just put .cs files anywhere and they'll work just the same.

Here's a nice link explaining the differences:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd547590.aspx